# Dropdowns in the form not resetting after adding id to the select in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to reset the form fields. I have 2 selects with Select2 in JS. If I remove the id of any of the 2 selects it will reset, else it will stay the same.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#fieldName").select2();
  $("#actionName").select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js" integrity="sha512-2ImtlRlf2VVmiGZsjm9bEyhjGW4dU7B6TNwh/hx/iSByxNENtj3WVE6o/9Lj4TJeVXPi4bnOIMXFIJJAeufa0A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" integrity="sha512-nMNlpuaDPrqlEls3IX/Q56H36qvBASwb3ipuo3MxeWbsQB1881ox0cRv7UPTgBlriqoynt35KjEwgGUeUXIPnw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<form>
  <table>
    <tbody id="table_achievements_tbody">
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>
          <select class="form-control" id="fieldName" style="width:280px;">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">Field Name</option>
            <option value="1">Div 2</option>
            <option value="2"> Div 1</option>
          </select>
        </th>
        <th>
          <select class="form-control" id="actionName" style="width:280px;">
            <option selected>Select action</option>
            <option>Equals</option>
            <option>Greater than</option>
            <option>Less than</option>
          </select>
        </th>
        <th><input type="text" id="text2" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Value" style="width:280px;"></th>
        <th style="width: 120px;">
          <select class="form-control sell" name="argSelect">
            <option value="Arg">Argument</option>
            <option value="AND">AND</option>
            <option value="OR">OR</option>
            <option value="ONLY">ONLY</option>
          </select>
        </th>
        <th style="width:54.58px;"></th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<button type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">clear</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What does `select2()` do?

Comment: it's a plugin that add searchable dropdown lists

Comment: [reset select2](https://www.google.com/search?q=reset+select2+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the reset button only works on form controls. The Select2 library hides the original `select` element and creates a new HTML structure to allow the searching and selection of options. This is not part of a standard form control, so is unaffected by the `reset` action.

To address this you can hook to the `reset` event of the `form` element and manually reset the Select2 instances to their default values, as demonstrated in the below example.

Also note in the following example that I moved the inline `style` rules in to their own stylesheet. It's bad practice to mix CSS/JS and HTML, so this should be avoided wherever possible.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#fieldName, #actionName').select2();

  $('form').on('reset', () => {
    $('#fieldName').val('0').trigger('change');
    $('#actionName').val('Select action').trigger('change');
  });
});
```

```css
#fieldName,
#actionName,
#text2 {
  width: 280px;
}

th.standard {
  width: 120px;
}

th.narrow {
  width: 54.58px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js" integrity="sha512-2ImtlRlf2VVmiGZsjm9bEyhjGW4dU7B6TNwh/hx/iSByxNENtj3WVE6o/9Lj4TJeVXPi4bnOIMXFIJJAeufa0A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" integrity="sha512-nMNlpuaDPrqlEls3IX/Q56H36qvBASwb3ipuo3MxeWbsQB1881ox0cRv7UPTgBlriqoynt35KjEwgGUeUXIPnw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<form>
  <table>
    <tbody id="table_achievements_tbody">
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>
          <select class="form-control" id="fieldName">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">Field Name</option>
            <option value="1">Div 2</option>
            <option value="2"> Div 1</option>
          </select>
        </th>
        <th>
          <select class="form-control" id="actionName">
            <option selected>Select action</option>
            <option>Equals</option>
            <option>Greater than</option>
            <option>Less than</option>
          </select>
        </th>
        <th>
          <input type="text" id="text2" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Value">
        </th>
        <th class="narrow">
          <select class="form-control sell" name="argSelect">
            <option value="Arg">Argument</option>
            <option value="AND">AND</option>
            <option value="OR">OR</option>
            <option value="ONLY">ONLY</option>
          </select>
        </th>
        <th class="narrow"></th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">clear</button>
</form>
```